# Does any international organization (such as IMF) provide data on capital control / financial openness?

Tags: macroeconomics, data-request, financial-economics

I've read some literature on measuring capital control / financial openness, but I am wondering if there is any data directly collected by international organizations like IMF that measure capital control.

Comment: Data like cardinal data on the intensity of capital controls or just time series data on which countries have capital controls in each year?

Answer (score 2):

Indeed the IMF reports on this. A recent review-overview paper is

[**Quinn, D., Schindler, M., & Toyoda, A. M. (2011). Assessing measures of financial openness and integration. IMF Economic Review, 59(3), 488-522.**](http://www18.georgetown.edu/data/people/quinnd/publication-64463.pdf)

In the introduction, the authors write

> *"The aim of this article is to help researchers better understand the range of choices they have in measuring financial integration and
>   globalization, the pros and cons associated with each, and some of the
>   reasons behind the divergence in findings in the literature. In
>   particular, it describes de jure, de facto, and “hybrid” indicators,
>   and comparatively analyzes their data properties and how these
>   measures relate to one another"*

The main "De jure" (as the authors characterize it) resource (on which many scholars have built various indexes using wildly different methodologies) is the IMF's report [***Annual Report on Exchange
Arrangements and Exchange Restrictions (AREAER)***](http://www.imf.org/external/ns/search.aspx?NewQuery=Annual%20Report%20on%20Exchange%20Arrangements%20and%20Exchange%20Restrictions&submit.x=13&submit.y=14&col=)

As the authors write, after presenting the various "De jure" indices,

> *"De jure indices of financial globalization do not reflect the extent to which actual capital flows evolve in response to legal
>   restrictions, either because of a lack of enforcement, or because
>   controls in one area may induce a response in other asset flows. Also,
>   even the more disaggregated indices may not capture subtle, but
>   possibly important differences between countries’ capital control
>   regimes. De jure measures, therefore, do not necessarily reflect a
>   country’s actual degree of financial integration, highlighted by the
>   fact that even countries with relatively closed capital accounts
>   became substantially more financially integrated over the past
>   decades... Thus, "de facto", or in some cases “blended,” measures
>   present an alternative way to measure a country’s integration into
>   global finance markets. These can be divided into three categories:
>   quantity-based, price-based, and hybrid measures."*

They then move on to a detailed study of many of all the above indices, and they conclude (they have also conveniently summarized qualitative assessments of each index in tables):

> *"A key result is that most of the measures provide information that is linked in a meaningful way to economic outcomes. The exception is
>   IF-Heritage, an indicator that we found not to be correlated with
>   other indices, to have no measurable impact on economic growth, and to
>   be linked in the factor analysis to unique dynamics that are not
>   easily interpretable. Correlation and factor analyses suggest that
>   investigators using de facto indicators of financial globalization
>   will find differing identifying variances from those found in the de
>   jure measures. In part, this is because de facto measures likely
>   reflect the influences of many political and economic factors, of
>   which legal restrictions of the capital accounts, as indicated by the
>   de jure measures, are but one."*

and

> *"The bottom line of this paper is that researchers in this field have an unusually large choice of indicators, most of which are valid, with
>   unique advantages and disadvantages."*